# Use sed to insert analytics code to most html files

Tags: html, bash, sed, google-analytics

I have so many static html files (well over a thousand) without Google Analytics code.

my challenge is, not all html files are without Analytics code. this is the folder structure of the files that should have Analytics code added:

`user/[user ID]/sites/[site ID]/`

there are more than one html files in those folders. I can't simply use `sed` on all html files because following files in same "users" folder already have the Analytics js code:

`user/[user ID]/editor/index.html`

moreover, my html files end with  in one line.

How can I add a js code (i.e. Analytics) right before  and exclude all the`user/[user ID]/editor/index.html` files from the process?

Comment: I use Nginx with no PageSpeed support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find` and exclude the proper files.

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*users/[0-9]*/sites/[0-9]*/.*html' -exec sed -i 's/pattern/replace/g' "{}" \;
```

You can always exclude files from that find, say files `.*/sites/.*/index.html`:

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*users/[0-9]*/sites/[0-9]*/.*html' -not -name "*index.html" -exec sed -i 's/pattern/replace/g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: but this worked. thanks

`find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*user/[0-9]*/sites/[0-9]*/.*html' -exec sed -i 's*</BODY>\|</body>*\
<script>\
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1\*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),\
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\
        })(window,document,"script","//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");\
        ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXX-X", "auto");\
        ga("send", "pageview");\
</script>&*' "{}" \;`